# Java encrypting with USB certificates (smart cards)

Tags: java, encryption, smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm writing a Java program which is encrypting and signing with USB certificates (smart cards). I have a shared library (.dll on Windows, .so on Linux) which implements PKCS11 for the hardware.

I was searching for existing solutions and found the following guide http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html The guide suggests to use sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 provider.

However, I have major problems with sun.security.pkcs11 package. I managed to make signature working, but I cannot make encryption / decryption. I was searching and found that developers should not use 'sun' packages http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Now, I'm wondering what should I use instead of sun.security.pkcs11?

I have a working C++ code (which is using NSS library to work with the hardware). I found, that NSS library is using C_WrapKey and C_UnwrapKey for encrption.

The following code should probably use C_WrapKey and C_UnwrapKey for encrption, but I can see in the logs of the .so library that the java code calls C_DecryptInit which for some reason fails (C_DecryptInit() Init operation failed.).

Note: Both (Cipher.PUBLIC_KEY/Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY and Cipher.WRAP_MODE/Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE works fine with soft certificates). The code works with hard certificates only with Java 1.7 (32-bit Java on Windows machine).

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: init() failed
        at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.implInit(P11RSACipher.java:239)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.engineUnwrap(P11RSACipher.java:479)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.unwrap(Cipher.java:2510)
        at gem_test.Test.decryptDocument(Test.java:129)
        at gem_test.Test.main(Test.java:81)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_KEY_FUNCTION_NOT_PERMITTED
        at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_DecryptInit(Native Method)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.initialize(P11RSACipher.java:304)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.P11RSACipher.implInit(P11RSACipher.java:237)
        ... 4 more
```

Code:

```
package gem_test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11;

public class Test {
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";

    static int hard_soft = 1; // 1 - smart card, 2 - soft certificate
    static int sign_encrypt = 2; // 1- sign, 2 - encryption


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PrivateKey privateKey;
        PublicKey pubKey;
        if (hard_soft == 1) {
            String pkcsConf = (
                "name = Personal\n" +
                "library = /usr/local/lib/personal/libP11.so\n" +
//                    "library = c:\\perso\\bin\\personal.dll\n" +
                "slot = 0\n"
            );

            char[] pin = "123456".toCharArray();
            String useCertAlias = "Digital Signature";
//                String useCertAlias = "Non Repudiation";

            SunPKCS11 provider = new SunPKCS11(new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcsConf.getBytes()));
            String providerName = provider.getName();
            Security.addProvider(provider);

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", providerName);
            keyStore.load(null, pin);

            privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(useCertAlias, pin);
            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(useCertAlias);
            pubKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
        } else if (hard_soft == 2) {
            /*
             mkdir /tmp/softkey
             cd /tmp/softkey

             openssl genrsa 2048 > softkey.key
             chmod 400 softkey.key
             openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -days 365 -key softkey.key -out softkey.crt
             openssl pkcs12 -export -in softkey.crt -inkey softkey.key -out softkey.pfx
             rm -f softkey.key softkey.crt
             */
            String pfx = "/tmp/softkey/softkey.pfx";
            String useCertAlias = "1";

            KeyStore keyStore1 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore1.load(new FileInputStream(pfx), new char[]{});

            privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore1.getKey(useCertAlias, new char[]{});
            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore1.getCertificate(useCertAlias);
            pubKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        if (sign_encrypt == 1) {
            byte[] sig = signDocument("msg content".getBytes(), privateKey);
            boolean result = verifyDocument("msg content".getBytes(), sig, pubKey);
            System.out.println("RESULT " + result);
        } else if (sign_encrypt == 2) {
            byte[] encrypted = encryptDocument("msg content".getBytes(), pubKey);
            byte[] decryptedDocument = decryptDocument(encrypted, privateKey);
            System.out.println("RESULT " + new String(decryptedDocument));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    private static byte[] signDocument(byte[] aDocument, PrivateKey aPrivateKey) throws Exception {
        Signature signatureAlgorithm = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        signatureAlgorithm.initSign(aPrivateKey);
        signatureAlgorithm.update(aDocument);
        byte[] digitalSignature = signatureAlgorithm.sign();
        return digitalSignature;
    }

    private static boolean verifyDocument(byte[] aDocument, byte[] sig, PublicKey pubKey) throws Exception {
        Signature signatureAlgorithm = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        signatureAlgorithm.initVerify(pubKey);
        signatureAlgorithm.update(aDocument);
        return signatureAlgorithm.verify(sig);
    }


    private static byte[] encryptDocument(byte[] aDocument, PublicKey pubKey) throws Exception {
        int encrypt_wrap = 2;
        if (encrypt_wrap == 1) {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.PUBLIC_KEY, pubKey);
            return cipher.doFinal(aDocument);
        } else if (encrypt_wrap == 2) {
            SecretKey data = new SecretKeySpec(aDocument, 0, aDocument.length, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, pubKey);
            return cipher.wrap(data);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] decryptDocument(byte[] encryptedDocument, PrivateKey aPrivateKey) throws Exception {
        int encrypt_wrap = 2;
        if (encrypt_wrap == 1) {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY, aPrivateKey);
            return cipher.doFinal(encryptedDocument);
        } else if (encrypt_wrap == 2) {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, aPrivateKey);
            SecretKey res = (SecretKey) cipher.unwrap(encryptedDocument, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
            return res.getEncoded();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly related to (or duplicates) [PKCS11Exception: CKR_KEY_FUNCTION_NOT_PERMITTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887218/pkcs11exception-ckr-key-function-not-permitted)

Comment: Thanks @M.Prokhorov: I saw this. I have a working solution with C++ and NSS library, so hardware (smart card) should work.

Comment: Well, your exception documented as "An attempt has been made to use a key for a cryptographic purpose that the key’s attributes are not set to allow it to do". Are you sure that your java implementation uses your library? If so, maybe add a couple of log statements somewhere and check if all values passed correctly.

Comment: There is a good third party PKCS#11 wrapper and provider library by IAIK. 

https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/

Comment: @always_a_rookie_to_learn A previous version of the free wrapper was actually used by Sun to create the PKCS#11 provider; I would not be surprised if it would therefore generate the same error.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes. You are right, it would mostly throw the same error. I was pointing out to IAIK since the questioner was trying to find an alternative to the usage of `sun` package.

Comment: @always_a_rookie_to_learn I think using the wrapper directly could work come to think of it; if there are woring PKCS#11 calls in C then those could be replicated.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov It does, yet low level calls aren't the desired ones (C_DecryptInit instead of C_UnwrapKey).

Comment: @always_a_rookie_to_learn Thank you very much for the reference. I will definitely check it out, because I have a very hard time to get sun library working. This code works only with Java 1.7 on Linux machine and only with 32-bit Java 1.7 on Windows machine since sun package doesn't exist on 64-bit Java 1.7. Sun package does exist on Windows 64-bit Java 1.8, but the code throws a cryptic exception.

Answer (score 1):

In the end we used this solution for the problem of making / verifying signatures and encryption / decryption from Java 8 with smart cards. It works on both Linux and Windows using 64 bit Java.

We haven't managed to fix the Wrap / Unwrap part. I believe that it would be possible to fix the bug with `java.lang.instrument`, but instead we decided to replace all smartcards so that they support "Data Encipherement".

The code to monkey patch the JDK 8 SunPKCS11 provider bug:

```
String pkcsConf = (
    "name = \"Personal\"\n" +
    String.format("library = \"%s\"\n", hardCertLib) +
    String.format("slot = %d\n", slotId)
);

SunPKCS11 provider = new SunPKCS11(new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcsConf.getBytes()));
tryFixingPKCS11ProviderBug(provider);

....


/**
 * This a fix for PKCS11 bug in JDK8. This method prefetches the mech info from the driver.
 * @param provider
 */
public static void tryFixingPKCS11ProviderBug(SunPKCS11 provider) {
    try {
        Field tokenField = SunPKCS11.class.getDeclaredField("token");
        tokenField.setAccessible(true);
        Object token = tokenField.get(provider);

        Field mechInfoMapField = token.getClass().getDeclaredField("mechInfoMap");
        mechInfoMapField.setAccessible(true);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<Long, CK_MECHANISM_INFO> mechInfoMap = (Map<Long, CK_MECHANISM_INFO>) mechInfoMapField.get(token);
        mechInfoMap.put(PKCS11Constants.CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS, new CK_MECHANISM_INFO(1024, 2048, 0));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.info(String.format("Method tryFixingPKCS11ProviderBug failed with '%s'", e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is simply to use `ENCRYPT` instead of `WRAP` and `DECRYPT` instead of `UNWRAP`.

To understand why, it is important to see what `WRAP` and `UNWRAP` do.  Basically they perform simply `ENCRYPT` and `DECRYPT` but they simply return a key. Now if you do this in software then there is no difference *except* for the fact that you don't need to use a `SecretKeySpec` or `SecretKeyFactory` to regenerate a key from the decrypted data.

However if you perform it on hardware then generally the resulting key will be kept on the hardware device (or Token). This is of course fine if you possess a HSM: it can just generate a (session specific) key and return a handle. But on smart cards this is generally not possible. And even if it was: you don't want to send all of the message to the smart card to let it encrypt.

Furthermore, if you use Java you don't directly have control over the PKCS#11 input parameters to the wrapping or unwrapping calls.

---

So try `ENCRYPT` and `DECRYPT` and then regenerate the key in software.

Alternatively you could replicate the *PKCS#11* wrap and unwrap calls using the Open Source IAIK wrapper library; mimicking the C functionality. But that would not be compatible with calls that require the `Cipher` class.

---

Note that `RSA` in Sun providers in all likelihood means `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding`. If you need a different RSA algorithm then you should experiment with the algorithm string; this could also be the problem that you are facing: that you use the wrong algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the written. I need encryption/decryption for general purpose byte arrays, not to encrypt keys. I think that C_DecryptInit fails because the certificate is missing certain attributes (as @M.Prokhorov mentioned), but that attributes are not required to perform encryption with C_WrapKey / C_UnwrapKey (that is probably the reason why C++ code works). I will get a smart card which will have that attribute enabled and test with ENCRYPT/DECRYPT. Thanks :)